# Is there any need to register my arrival in Dubai/UAE?

Tags: visas, dubai, uae

I plan on visiting Dubai later in the year on holiday, and am staying with friends in their apartment. I understand that a visa-on-arrival should be straightforward for me (I am a UK citizen). However, because I'm not staying in a hotel, are there any registration or other procedures I need to undertake that otherwise the hotel might do for me? (I'm aware that's the case in Russia, for example). I might travel to other emirates, but I don't plan on leaving the U.A.E.

Answer (score 5):

No such registration procedure in UAE. Just write your friend's address in any form (if any).

source: first hand experience.